# R + NA's are not included

Tags: r, csv

Consider this file:

"a","b"

"a","v","d"

Now, if I read this in with:

```
d <- read.csv("tmp.txt", header=0, fill=TRUE);
```

then d becomes

a,b

a,b,c

whereas I want it to be

a,b,NA

a,b,c

so I can check for NA (since R doesnt have a is.empty operation). My question is: 
Why on earth doesnt read.csv just do this? I've tried every single combination and it doesnt work. However, if I exchange the rows and remove the header=0 option then it does work, but the first row becomes the header. So irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that empty strings should be interpreted as NA:

```
> d <- read.csv("tmp.txt", header = F, na.strings = c("", "NA"))
> d
  V1 V2   V3
1  a  b <NA>
2  a  v    d
```

Cheers!

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. I tried just na.string=c(""). Thanks a lot!